# Given two X509Certificate2 objects in C#, how can I check whether one issued the other?

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

I have a C# application where we make our own certificate chains based on our own root certificates.

Given a root certificate *c1* and an issued certificate *c2*, I want to check whether *c2* was issued by *c1* - i.e., whether *c1* is the "parent" of *c2* and that the two can form a valid chain.

How can I check this?

I am using .NET 6. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible method is, to create a chain from c2 and check inside the chain, if the root certificate is present (By comparing the Thumbprint):

```
private static bool CheckCertChain(X509Certificate2 rootCert, X509Certificate2 clientCert)
        {
            X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
            //Need to set revocation to no check
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            //Build the chain
            if (!chain.Build(clientCert))
                return false;
            //Check if the root is present in the chain
            return chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>().Any(cert => cert.Certificate.Thumbprint.Equals(rootCert.Thumbprint, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
```